# My App Runs on Test Device But Can't Install It On Any Other Device

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation, device

Im trying to create an android app with Android Studio and I also use Firebase.

My problem in my whole app is when I run on my testing device

-"Samsung j7, Android version is 6.0.1, Marshmallow = API level 23"

Everything is OK but when I try to put the application to the other device

-"Oppo F1 , ColorOS version 3.0.0i, Android version 5.1(I don't really know the API level of this)"

then the app can't install, and I have a message saying "Installation Failed" 
Don't really know what's the issue: the certificate, security, or something else...

When I create "hello world" app, and do the same thing as above everything is okay.

The unknown sources in setting is also enabled

my gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mcphil.avastus"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And when I start creating the app 
my minimum api level is Jelly bean = api level 18

manifest:EDIT : For Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mcphil.avastus">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    android:name="MathsQuiz">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SignupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LibraryActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".QuizzesActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DocumentActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".pdf.PDF_Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".quizzes.Quiz1Activity"/>
</application>
```

Don't know what else info from my side is needed for this, so just ask me if I'm missing something for the info needed, hope someone could help.

A lot of thanks
I'm very new in coding.

EDIT:
The new error is this :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'com.example.mcphil.avastus.Avastus'

The **.Avastus** in the last text in the error im trying to find where it comes.

Comment: Did you try reducing `targetSdkVersion` and then compiling it again? Are all the permissions required for your app listed in the `manifest`

Comment: from menu bar Build>BuildApk(s) and then take it and install

Comment: Working on it , I'm just irritated with the yellow lane that saying theres a new version of this 27.0.2 so I rise to 27.0.2.

Comment: I already tried reducing to targetSdkVersion to 26.0.2 and BuldApk , Clean Project, Rebuild Apk, still can't install to the other device , but in my testing device is okay ,, I only using java codes , , , No Logcat error . .

Btw the unknown sources of both devices is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works:

In Android studio, from the project panel Go to [app] > [build.gradle]  and Open build.gradle

Now Copy your ApplicationID, for example

> com.example.myApp

```js
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myApp" // ***----- Copy (com.example.myApp)
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
      ...
      ...
  }
```

Now Open your Browser, And Open [firebase.google.com] and then Click on [GO TO CONSOLE]

Then [Create a New Project] or [Add a Project]

and Enter a [Project Name] and a [Project ID] and [Your Country] - Whatever Name and ID you enter is Fine

Then a Page opens up like below: Click On [Add FireBase to your Android App]

[image]

Now, Here is where your [ApplicationId] need to be Used

Enter your Copied [ApplicationId] into [Android Project Name]

And Enter a Package Name - - Any Package Name is Fine . Then Click On [Register App]

[image]

On the Next Page --- DOWNLOAD Google-Service.json

[image]

When Download if Finished, Click [Continue] and then [FINISHED]

Now Take that Downloaded Json File, Copy it, And You must Paste it Into your Project, But You have to do it Twice.

Once From Android Studio, Once Normally in the Windows explorer

First, Paste it From Android Studio Into [App] Directory, by right Click on the [App] and pasting it

When you Paste Here, It Aks to "OverRide" and It Gives you an "IOExceptions" Error.

[image]

Both Are Fine CLick [Override] and [Ok]. You're fine

Then, Copy the Json that you Just Pasted in Android Studio, Right CLick, Copy.(Copy it from right inside the android studio itself)

[image]

And Now, Paste it Into the [App] directory from the windows explorer. Paste and Replace. ( for exmaple, C:\Users\Dell... | Where your Application is)

FINALLY, In Android Studio, Go to [File] And Click [Syncronize]

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to Match the Gradle ApplicationId to FireBase Project Name Again. I saw someone do this and it worked on a Test app, But You need to know THE Only Devastating Outcome when developing an Android app Is to Lose your Signing Keys. Everything Else Can be Fixed No matter what

Comment: Many Thanks , I Really appreciate your effort , btw , I do it, Multiple Time now in many different ways, I follow your steps I create a new Firebase Project download the json file and paste it in the directory and sync. But still got the error, and i experiment it with my existing firebase account and download the json file again in the project settings and paste it in directory of my app still got the same error,, 

btw the project name in the json file is the same with manifest and applicationID,

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT! I got it now, Thanks a lot ! 
but i just want to update your answer if in case ..

Comment: Avastus, Try to Create One Healthy FireBase Account And you should be set to go.

Comment: Update the Answer However you like, I was going to Stay until you try it, But I had to go.

Comment: Okay I will try it

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, Everything is okay now

Answer (score 1):

No app can be installed on other Devices Unless they are Connected to PC while running Android Studio.

But try to Generate a Signed Debug APK for testing on other devices, It has to be Signed. Phones cannot install Unsigned Apks for security Reasons

Comment: I try your Signed Debug Apk , And also Provide Key Stores 
But still can't install in the other device ,

And now i think i tweak something in android studio and got this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'Package Name'

I feel Android Studio is very Sensitive ,

Comment: Hi avastus, Will you check is the "package" name in your Manifest is the same as applicationId "com.example.mcphil.avastus" from your Gradle? The application ID must match the package name if your app. If it's a match, the problem is just a Google Service dependency issue and you can try to add Two class paths in Gradle dependency

Comment: Reply to the comment if you checked, I can write a new answer with instructions on how you can try adding dependency to your Gradle, but I'll search a bit before I suggest anything else

Comment: Yes, I already checked it, they are the same, I really scared now tweaking this android studio ,i have already got a lots of codes in it and try multiple times in real device and its works fine but this time why this happen.

Yes can you provide me an instructions ? 
i searched it too but still im confuse

Comment: Shahin, I updated the questions above , also I put the error

Comment: Don't Worry, I'm online, I'm writing a new answer, You'll fix it For sure, An'sd don't worry about your codes either, I'm sending some instructions in just a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

In this error:**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. No matching client found for package name 'com.example.your.package.name'**

you can follow the instructions by **Shahin**.

In my case and for some cases you need to redownload the google-services.json from existing firebase project in project settings

[Project Settings Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7w6W.png)

and copy it into your app directory where the saved project from your Android studio -paste it/replace-

and then

go back to the android studio, goto Tools>Firebase

[Tools>Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk2uL.png)

and then select Authentication

[Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sFzU.png)

Then Add **Firebase Authentication to your app**

and then **Connect your app to Firebase**

Once all set up and connected goto *Build>Make Project*

and thats it ,

> **But now, Im back to my real problem I mentioned above, My app only run on specified device connected via usb for real device test but still the app failed to install to the other devices.**